# Months between sysdate to earlier date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to get the months between current date to earlier date.

```
SELECT  MONTHS_BETWEEN(to_date(fld_valid_from,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),TO_DATE(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) num_months
 FROM   tbl_customer
```

But it's not working. I don't know if that's correct or not.

Comment: Which data type is `fld_valid_from`, and how is it not working? Do you get an error message, or an incorrect result?

Answer (score 1):

sysdate is already a date, and does not need to be converted to one using to_date(). I suspect that fld_valid_from is also a date.

Comment: Don't understand -- docs here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions102.htm

Comment: `select sysdate, months_between(sysdate, date '2013-01-01') from dual;`

`16-JUL-13                                6.5140961`

Answer (score 0):

What error message are you getting? Did you try comparing the two variables without the TO_DATE command?

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN (trunc(fld_valid_from),trunc(sysdate))
FROM tbl_customer
```

This would work if your column fld_valid_from is a date type. You're comparing a date with another date. You use TO_DATE to convert a string data type to a date data type.

With the TRUNC function, you remove the timestamp from the date, and get only...well, the date:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE                    TRUNC(SYSDATE)
---------------------------------------
16/07/2013 10:45:53        16/07/2013
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.